# no css is getting applied when i use localpath to include bootstrap.min.css , it works when i use CDN url instead of localpath

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.3.x. I want to include CSS using localpath but the CSS is not getting applied if I do so. below is the localpath.

I have tried placing the following source URL to include bootstrap.min.css which does not work

`link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"`

Where as when I use the below CDN path, it works.

`link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"`

including localpath should show proper elements in index.file. as of now, it shows scattered elements. I  checked the browser console, and I am getting the below errors

> 1. Access to CSS stylesheet at 'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/resumo/css/bootstrap.min.css' from origin
>    'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>    supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>    https.

> 2 . Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Check your browser console for errors and paste them in your question.

Comment: hey @nick, i have just added browser console errors to my question.

Comment: Ah, I think you are trying to access html file incorrectly. You need to try accessing your html file using something like this : `http://localhost:<port if provided any>/<folder under xampp>/<filename>.html`

Comment: Thanks @Nik, you are correct. its working when i turn the xamp on and access it using localhost.

Comment: Glad that helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to directly open the file in browser which caused issue for css loading. Actually, I need to turn on the web server (`apache` on `xampp` in my case) and access the file using http protocol with url `http://localhost/project/filename`.

Thanks to Nik who find the answer for me

Comment: Accept your own answer so that it will help others.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, and don't know how to accept answers. is accepting means giving upvote to my answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/ have a look at this.

Answer (score 3):

simply delete all these lines from your `href` code

```
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

and keep only this line

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

or you can just copy this line and replace yours with it. just make sure your files are in the same folder as your `index.html`

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
```